# Why the same One tap sign-in code can work at some moments and raise error at others?

Tags: android, google-one-tap

I made Googles authorization via [One tap sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials) library. At first it worked well, we added everything it demands:

- Web application credentials;
- Android debug credentials;
- Android release credentials;

But at some point it stopped consistently working - without code changes it throws exception:

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Developer console is not set up correctly

And in the same way it could start working again without code changes as well. And it's the worst - why the same code can work and throw exceptions in different moments? How can I affect that?

Here is My code:

```
private data class LaunchSignInOptions(
    val filterByAuthorizedAccounts: Boolean,
    val autoSelectEnabled: Boolean,
)

class AuthenticationWorker(
    private val activity: AppCompatActivity,
) {
    private val oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(activity)

    fun launchLogIn(onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
        launchLogIn(
            LaunchSignInOptions(
                filterByAuthorizedAccounts = true,
                autoSelectEnabled = true,
            ),
            onError,
        )
    }

    private fun launchLogIn(launchSignInOptions: LaunchSignInOptions, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
        val signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                .build())
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    .setServerClientId(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(launchSignInOptions.filterByAuthorizedAccounts)
                    .build())
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(launchSignInOptions.autoSelectEnabled)
            .build()
        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                activity.startIntentSenderForResult(
                    it.pendingIntent.intentSender, RequestCodes.REQUIRE_ONE_TAP,
                    null, 0, 0, 0, null)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                val statusCode = (it as? ApiException)?.statusCode
                when {
                    statusCode == CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED &&
                            launchSignInOptions.filterByAuthorizedAccounts -> {
                        launchLogIn(launchSignInOptions.copy(filterByAuthorizedAccounts = false), onError)
                    }
                    statusCode == CommonStatusCodes.DEVELOPER_ERROR &&
                            launchSignInOptions.autoSelectEnabled -> {
                        launchLogIn(launchSignInOptions.copy(autoSelectEnabled = false), onError)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        onError(it)
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener {
                Log.e("AuthenticationWorker", "cancelled")
            }
    }
}
```

You can ignore `LaunchSignInOptions` class as it's just experiment trying to fix the problem. I'm not sure if it's usefull.

Main flow goes to either `onFailureListener` and stops there or to `onSuccessListener` and successfully ends. I tried everything I could, I need help here.

**Update 2023-07-08**

Authorization can still unexpectedly fail, but now in next step - after dialog. But error is still same.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when(requestCode) {
        RequestCodes.REQUIRE_ONE_TAP -> {
            authenticationWorker.setResult(data)
        }
    }
}

fun setResult(data: Intent?) {
    try {
        val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
        loadUser(credential.id, credential.googleIdToken)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        //it falls here
    }
}
```

Comment: I share the same frustration. The most concerning aspect is the uncertainty surrounding whether the issue has genuinely been resolved after making adjustments in the developer console settings.

Answer (score -1):

follow this guide. [troubleshooting google](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting)

When i had the same problem i've fixed that by signing all build variants.

```
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias "your_alias"
            keyPassword "your_password"
            storeFile file("your_file_jks_location")
            storePassword "your_password_for_jks_file"
        }
        release {
            keyAlias "your_release_alias"
            keyPassword "your_release_password"
            storeFile file("your_release_file_jks_location")
            storePassword "your_release_password_for_jks_file"
        }
    }
    (...)
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            (...)
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            (...)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have these. I believe without it app wouldn't ever work.